# Which is better – "election panel" or "nominating committee"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

Which is the better choice when I want to talk about a group of people whose task it is to nominate members for a board or the like – *nominating committee* or *election panel*? I've found both, but I haven't been able to determine which is the better choice – if, indeed, one is better than the other.

Thank you!

Comment: The term [***nomination committee***](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/n/nominationcommittee.asp#:~:text=A%20nomination%20committee%20evaluates%20a,vary%20from%20company%20to%20company.) has a fairly "fixed" domain-specific definition: *A nomination committee evaluates a firm's board of directors and examines the skills and characteristics required of board candidates. Nomination committees may also have other duties, which vary from company to company.* If that's what you mean, use it. Otherwise, use ***election panel***, which really just means whatever you like in context.

Comment: (***nomination committee*** has strong ***commercial*** management associations, ***election panel*** is more likely in ***political*** contexts.)

Comment: I agree that **nomination committee** may have specific meanings you want to avoid, but I cannot find any case of **election panel** being used the way you mean, and **election panel** is not usually used to mean "a group that nominates people", because the *nomination* is not the same thing as the *election*.

Comment: The best choice might actually be **nomination/nominating panel**, e.g., ["the Secretary has reappointed Ms Helen Williams AC to the nomination panel"](https://pmc.gov.au/news-centre/pmc/nomination-panel-abc-and-sbs-board-appointments-1) or ["The mayor’s education nominating panel, charged with recommending candidates to serve on the Board of Education, met for the first time Friday"](https://philadelphia.chalkbeat.org/2018/1/19/22185830/nominating-panel-convenes-for-first-meeting)